# Ubuntu Server 11.10 iso image is loading desktop

Tags: 11.10, server

I am trying to load Server 11.10 i386 form an iso image on a usb stick. It loaded desktop instead. does not run tasksel during install and definitely loads GUI.

Anybody else having this problem?

In the iso file under .disk/info it shows "Ubuntu-Server 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" - Release i386 (20111011)"

I'm downloading another copy now and see if its the same.

Stumped

Thanks

Comment: did you check the Ubuntu md5sum

Comment: I looked at that and not sure exactly what to look for but the top lines show "./dists/oneiric/Release". Anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM this should help

Comment: Thanks for that info BlueXrider! I followed the guidelines on the How To and came up with a match for 11.10 Ubuntu Server i386 for the iso. All but three files match the md5sum.txt file on the USB stick as well. The three files are similar to "./install/netboot/pxelinux.0". I tried to install on the same machine different hard drive with the same results. The laptop that I am creating the startup USB is 11.10 Desktop so not sure if that is an issue. I will try creating from a different machine and see what happens. Otherwise not sure what is going on.

Comment: Grab a copy from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download and use Universal USB installer from here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: That worked just fine. Used UNetbootin instead. Just very odd. Thanks again for your help BlueXrider!!

Comment: Good. Glad to help. give me a +1 on the answer and accept it by checking the answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab a copy from here: [Ubuntu Download](http://ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download)

Use Universal USB installer from here: [USB Pendrive](http://pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3)

This should work.

Comment: accepted but I cannot vote up. Sorry. May and try and dig further here as well. Thanks again!